# jQuery - how to match closest() element by style?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I successfully managed to use `closest()` (http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest matching element by tag name. It basically goes up through DOM tree and returns element (if found) or false:

```
if(jQuery(".current_element").closest("p").length){ do something... }
//if above is TRUE then .current_element is nested within at least 1 "p"
```

Now, I'm trying to return TRUE only if ***any of tags*** (or rather the closest one to the element - the one that takes effect) have `style="text-align:center;"` applied. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:

```
if(jQuery(".current_element").closest("p").length && jQuery(".current_element").closest("p").css("text-align") == "center" ){
  do something...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, but it only considers `<p>` tag. Any ideas on how to expand it to support any tag with `text-align: center;`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the 'text-align: center" will indeed be an inline style, then you could add it directly to the selector when you call closest(), for example:

```
jQuery(".current_element").closest("p[style*='text-align:center']") ...
```

This will find an ancestor p elements that contain 'text-align:center' anywhere within the style attribute.

Comment: This one doesn't work for me and it only considers `<p>` tag. I already tested something like that before asking question.

Comment: Could you post the exact code you used along with your markup?

Comment: @robmisio If you mean mine exact code - it's in the question but it does not execute `do something...` part when I do `[style*='text-align:center']` instead of `p` used in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to have the `text-align: center;` applied by a class, and than you could easily select it.

Otherwise you could do basic string search, but for this to work it needs to be the exact string:

```
if ($('.current').closest('p').attr('style')=='text-align:center;')){ ... }
```

Comment: Doesn't work - or if it does then perhaps my `text-align:center;` is not exact match. But it displays just like that in source code - without spaces.

Comment: It would be great to see your code, especially the hierarchy of the HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.curr').closest("[style*='text-align:center']").length ...
```

Comment: This one doesn't work unfortunately and it only considers `<p>` tag. I already tested something like this before asking question.

Comment: This should do it... but its rather slow (since im using the 'containing' selector).

Comment: After your edit: it doesn't consider closest element now. It selects everything in document.

Comment: Allright, sorry I've interrputed your questions weirdly. check now

Comment: In theory that should do the trick but for some reason it doesn't. I ended up with this solution: `jQuery(".current_element").closest("*").css("text-align") == "center"`. Thanks for your suggestions though :)